# Efficient Sorting?

Tags: sorting

I've been looking an answer for this question for sometime now... "What is the most efficient way to sort a million 32-bit integers?"

I feel that Quick sort is the most efficient in sorting.. with an average Runtime of O(n*log n). (with the worst case O(n²))..

But some search results says that Radix sort/Merge sort are efficient for sorting million integers.

Any pointers?

Comment: There are many unanswered questions here that are important. For instance, is the input data partially sorted already? Or is it totally random? What's the distribution of the data, etc? Quicksort is wellknown more for being reasonanly decent most of the time, and rarely *really* bad, more-so than being the ultimate sorting algorithmn. There are certainly other contenders, for instance timsort, used in python: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timsort

Comment: If there was a single simple answer to this question, I think many of us would not have jobs.

Comment: What I find interesting is, what is the overall impact of sorting on your actual problem? I've seen developpers spending days on optimizing special algorithms like this, ignoring the fact that the sorting just contributed a non-significant amount to the actual runtime of the system whereas in other areas changes could be made to circumvent the real bottlenecks within minutes. Or is this just a theoretical question?

Answer (score 3):

Mergesort is guarenteed to be O(n lg n), but has a higher memory footprint than quick sort.

Quicksort generally runs faster than mergesort, but under ~some~ circumstances it can degrade to quadratic running time.

Radix sort is O(n*r) where r is the length of the numbers.

To determine if radix is better than your chosen lg-n method, do this:

```
n * r < n * lg (n)
divide by n on both sides
r < lg(n)

We know r is 32 bits

32 < lg(n)

for both sides, take 2^x

2^32 < 2^(lg(n)

2^32 < n
```

So if n is less than 2^32 (4 billion) then use the lg-n algorithm.

Personally, I'd use quick sort, shuffling it if I have to in order to prevent it from degrading.

Comment: Ever thought about the meaning of the O(...) notation? It's not as simple as that.

Comment: @Yochai Sorting by digits is radix in base 10. Sorting by bits (which doesn't require the use of buckets) is done in base 2. You could use whatever base you want for it. If you can use base 10, why not just use base 2^32? You can take "32 bits" down to "8 digits" (of hex) if you want, or for that matter, if you want 256 buckets, you can take it down to 4... but you incur additional costs.

Comment: @Axel You have two parts to your comment, and I feel both are in need of explanation for them to be anything but flame bait.

Comment: You should know the actual computation if you're concerned by performance . if you get k*d*N iterations it's a big difference if the limit is 1000 iterations or 10000 iterations. big O is just computational complexity. 100000 iteration * N is still big O(N).

Comment: @Yochai You are correct that in this case O(k*d*N) is reduced to O(N) due to the relative size between the two. The additional costs I was referring to was the extra cost of the memory of the buckets. Allow me to iterate **Radix sort does not require buckets or extra memory**. I'm at work so I don't have the time to code it up, but essentially, when you use base 2 (bit level) as your radix, you sort any size array in N*bits comparisons in place, and the only additional memory you need is a handful (I believe it's 3) additional ints.

Comment: @Yochai If you did the int-to-string-to-int conversion, you could use char as a radix, although you would have to have 258 additional ints instead. You would ~not~ have to allocate buckets with a total size among them of N like you would with bucket sort.

Comment: After a quick calculation you're proven right with bits being better if you take into account the actual formula (lets say NlogN has a constant C): d = 2 , k = 32 ... 2*32*n < C*nlogn ---> 2^64 < n^C ... d = 10 , k = 10 ... 10*10*n < C*nlogn ---> 2^100 < n^C ... We see that base 2 is much better. And It's safe to assume that C here is about 1~2

Comment: Again, big O is just complexity. It's not the only thing you need to calculate. "" Because big O notation discards multiplicative constants on the running time, and ignores efficiency for low input sizes, it does not always reveal the fastest algorithm in practice or for practically-sized data sets, but the approach is still very effective for comparing the scalability of various algorithms as input sizes become large.""

Comment: glowcoder: why shuffle? You can just use a [pivot selection method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort#Choice_of_pivot) that avoids the degradation for sorted arrays. The degradation is still there but in a less common case (same thing can happen when you shuffle).

Comment: @glowcoder O(n log(n)) just is short for t=c1*n*log(n)+c2 with c1 and c2 being constants not dependent on n. And O(n*r) stands for t=c3*n*r+c4, c3 and c4 again being constants not dependent on n. This gives you two equations with 4 undetermined values, and all you can tell is that if n is "big enough", the n*r version will perform better. But to just assume c1=c2=c3=c4=1 will almost certainly not give you the correct result.

Comment: @Axel I gave OP the tools to use to decide which method was best for him. Only he knows the constants to the algorithms he's using. I mentioned here in the comments various ways I would reduce the constants. I'm not oblivious to them, and I would expect by the quality of the post that neither is the OP, and that it's a fairly straightforward extension to include them.

Comment: @glowcoder But you completely ignored those constants in your answer and recommend "So if n is less than 2^32 (4 billion) then use the lg-n algorithm". This just won't work, because the threshold might as well be any other value, which is impossible to tell based on what is given in the OPs question.

Answer (score 1):

if you have enough space maybe you can try bucket sort (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bucket_sort). It's more efficient but requires additional memory to store datas.

Comment: They are equivalent. Bucket sort is a kind of Radix sort.

Answer (score 0):

Radix is better if for large numbers, especially when you know the range of the numbers.

**Calculation fix:**

Radix is **O(kN)** where **k** is the number of digits in the largest number.  (Actually it's about **d*k*N** where **d** is the digit base, number of buckets that will be used ... Alphabet = 26, decimal = 10 , binary = 2)

Maxint =  4,294,967,296
32 bits: k = 32 / log(d)

Base 10 Radix:

```
d*k*n = 10*10*n < nlogn .... 100 < logn ... n > 2^100
```

Base 2 Radix:

```
d*k*n = 2*32*n < nlogn .... 64 < logn ... n > 2^64
```

So for 32bit numbers if you have more than 2^64 numbers **n*k*N** is better than **nlogn**

But, if you know that the range will be up to 1024 , and not MAXINT for example:

MaxNumber =  1024

Base 10 Radix:

```
d*k*n = 10*4*n < nlogn .... 40 < logn ... n > 2^40
```

Base 2 Radix:

```
d*k*n = 2*10*n < nlogn .... 20 < logn ... n > 2^20
```

So for numbers up to 1024 if you have more than 2^20 numbers **n*k*N** is better than **nlogn**

> Because big O notation discards
>   multiplicative constants on the
>   running time, and ignores efficiency
>   for low input sizes, it does not
>   always reveal the fastest algorithm in
>   practice or for practically-sized data
>   sets, but the approach is still very
>   effective for comparing the
>   scalability of various algorithms as
>   input sizes become large.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, you also need to take into account lg(k) as well when using characters instead of bits, unless you're using buckets which makes it bucket sort instead.

Comment: Radix does use buckets. Added the size of alphabet for the number of buckets that will be used.

Comment: When using strings d will either be 256 (byte) or less if you know you're getting only alphanumeric, or predefined and know characters. K will then be then number of characters (average, but take max for safety)

Answer (score 0):

Merge sort is O(n log n) in its worst case, so its going to be better than quick sort most of the time.  Radix sorts, iirc, are only really useful when each thing being sorted is the same length.  Its timed in O(K * N) which is (item length) * (number of items).  I don't think I've ever needed to use a Radix sort.

Comment: "Better than quicksort most of the time" [citation needed].

Comment: what citation needed? if your worst case is as good as the best case for another algorithm, that's all the citation you need.  It's just plain math.  But if you want to be all wiki about it, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort will tell you that merge sort's worst case does 39% fewer comparisons than quicksort's average case, so even in the average case, you're still better off with a merge sort than a quick sort.

Comment: but that same wikipedia article says "On typical modern architectures, efficient quicksort implementations generally outperform mergesort for sorting RAM-based arrays.", so you're still better of with... wait what?

Comment: Martinho -- The efficiency of an algorithm, and the one you choose, is also going to depend on your data structure.  For instance, if you're storing data in a hash table then you won't often need to sort since you're almost always going to have a constant access time of O(1) to do your lookup and sorting isn't necessary.  Quicksort is easy enough to implement and performs fairly well, and is usually 'good enough,' but without more information from the OP, and based solely on the math, merge sort is better without having to rely on compiler optimizations or specific architectures.